# Which is better in performance wise javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, performance

I want to create  browser editor like ms word for browser.for that what should I used javascript or jquery? Which is better in performance wise javascript or jquery?

Comment: jQuery is programmed using javascript. So what do you think?

Comment: jQuery *IS* JavaScript

Comment: Performance-wise: plain JavaScript. But good luck getting good browser-compatibility without jQuery for such a large project. jQuery will help with DOM traversal/manipulation, Events, and AJAX (among other things)

Comment: Um, recreating the wheel? http://ckeditor.com/, http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/, etc

Comment: @epascarello Given the choice between an all-terrain tire and the ability to make my own tire specifically designed for mountainous roads, I'd take the custom-made one any day.

Comment: @Kolink And with a question like this, do you think the OP has the ability to make that tire? ;)

Comment: jQuery is a very large abstraction from the DOM API, as well as from parts of the native language API. Well written jQuery code will almost always be slower than well written native code. Doesn't mean there's no place for jQuery, but its downsides do need to be carefully weighed.

Comment: @epascarello No, but OP may have the ability to get the ability (ie. to learn)

Comment: Yep, you gotta start somewhere. You never learn if you never try.

Answer (score 6):

The most powerful kind of JavaScript is [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/). All other JavaScript frameworks are built using it, and are therefore by definition slower.

To elaborate some, we live in an age where people want to do things fast. Used to be a time where everyone had dialup and where 10kB was a ***ton of memory. Just because we now have more bandwidth and more RAM is NOT an excuse to program shoddily. If you don't take the time to mercilessly squeeze every last drop of efficiency out of your code, then you are not a real programmer. This is especially true of JavaScript, because you have no idea whether the user will have an Alienware or an eeePC. You don't know if they have fibre-optics or dialup. You don't know if they're using IE10 or IE6 (well, that last one can be discovered by the UA string, but that's not the point). The point is you need to make sure your code works as efficiently as possible. People on slow connections/computers/browsers will appreciate being able to get anything done, and those on fast ones will be amazed at how instantly everything works.

Comment: Haha I never actually read through that website, but pretty funny :)

Comment: 25 bytes gzipped is too much for my development requirements.